# strstr not performing upto expectations

Tags: c

i cant seem to find whats wrong with my logic that the `strstr` not performing upto my expectations

its a question to find prime number in a binary string, and i'm finding `10` or `11` in that string and the outcome is not what i've expected.

sorry if i've done a terrible silly mistake, i'm a noob.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        char str[100000];
        scanf("%s", str);
        char ten[] = "10";
        char eleven[] = "11";
        int flag = 0;
        if (strstr(str, ten) == NULL)
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        else if (strstr(str,eleven) == NULL)
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
        else if (flag == 0)
        {
            printf("YES\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input providing is

```
3 //test cases
1 //strings
111
101101
```

output getting

```
NO
NO
YES
```

output expecting

```
NO
YES
YES
```

Comment: What input are you providing? What output are you expecting? What output are you getting?

Comment: wait @DavidSchwartz let me add it to question.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you expect "111" to give a "YES"? "111" contains no "10". So the first call to `strstr` will return `NULL` causing you to set `flag` to `1`. Your code outputs `NO` if `flag` is set to `1`. (I can't tell where in this line of reasoning you went awry because I have no idea what any line of your code is supposed to do because it has no comments. I can only see what it does, and it is clearly designed to output "NO" for "111".)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i think i've got what i'm doing wrong, but letme explain you what i was trying to do and what i wanna do. `111` contains no `10` but after that there's another else if statement to check if `111` contains `11` but what's wrong with this is that it'll check only for `10` and skip elseif.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i wanna check if the input string has `11` or `10`. that's it. so for `111` it has `11` so it'll return me yes.

Comment: Why not do `int flag = 1;` and then `if (strstr(str, ten)) flag = 0; else if (strstr(str,eleven)) flag = 0; ...`? (start with `flag` set to `1` and require `strstr()` to *Succeed* before setting the flag `0`)

Comment: Well, to output `YES`, `flag` has to stay zero. But you set it to one if there's no "10". Why do you do that?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so suggest me how to get my desired output.

Comment: @TusharKamboj - re-read my comment... and Note, `0` usually means (false/no) while `1` means (true/yes) -- so your choice of mappings for `1` and `0` can be confusing -- perhaps even to yourself.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks mate, i've posted a answer that i adjusted. check it and tell me if i can improve it to make it more readable to you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want your code to output "YES" for "111". For that to happen, you must leave `flag` at zero. But you set `flag` to one if the string contains no "10" and "111" contains no "10".

Answer (score 0):

this code is working fine. i've made some adjustments, thanks to you guys.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        char str[100000];
        scanf("%s", str);
        char ten[] = "10";
        char eleven[] = "11";
        int flag = 1;
        char *one = strstr(str, ten);
        char *two = strstr(str, eleven);
        if ((one == NULL) && (two == NULL))
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
        else if (flag == 1)
        {
            printf("YES\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you reversed the `0` and `1` mapping. That looks fine. You should also check the return any time `scanf()` contains a numeric-conversion, e.g. `if (scanf("%d", &t) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer value.\n", stderr); return 1; }`

Comment: the problem was with if statement. If first two characters are not '10', if statement would just terminate there not checking for eleven. Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the if Statement. If '10' is not found in the first two characters, it would terminate there. Not checking for 11 also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int t;
    scanf(" %d", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        char str[100000];
        scanf(" %s", str);
        char ten[] = "10";
        char eleven[] = "11";
        int flag = 0;
        if (strstr(str, ten) == NULL && strstr(str,eleven) == NULL)
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        if (flag == 1)
            printf("NO\n");
        else
            printf("YES\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```